# UiWebview in IPhone resize as per the content size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

[image]I am having an issue like i am using UIWebView in Iphone and data coming as HTML am storing the html data as astring and passing to the UIWebView am getting it in good but **i want to Change the UIWebView Size as per the content size**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        web.delegate = self; 
        NSString * str = [dict objectForKey:@"terms"];
        [web loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];
    }
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
        CGRect frame = web.frame;
        frame.size.height = 1;

        CGSize fittingSize = [web sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
        frame.size = fittingSize;
        web.frame = frame;

        NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);

     web.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, web.scrollView.contentSize.width, web.scrollView.contentSize.height);

}
```

Comment: R u using AutoLayouts..?

Comment: no am not using auto layouts

Comment: set self.webview.frame=self.view.frame; or 
self.webview.frame=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

Comment: your web view contain is small ?, Because web view have scroll it self..

Comment: i drag and drop one UIWebView in to ViewController and created property and am using that to display the content

Comment: yaa i know that it has scrollview but i want to display the full content with out scroll view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your `web view delegate` and `frame`.

```
 yourwebview.frame=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; 
 yourwebview.delegate = self;
```

end then use this delegate method to set height.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
        CGSize contentSize = aWebView.scrollView.contentSize;
        NSLog(@"webView contentSize: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(contentSize));
        yourwebview.contentsize = contentSize;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad:` but sometimes this is called before the HTML is fully rendered and that leads to wrong height values.

To make this work reliably you have to wait until the HTML is fully rendered and then use Javascript to send the correct height to your UIWebView.

Please have a look at this [blogpost](http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/set-the-height-of-a-uiwebview-to-the-height-of-its-html-content/) I wrote some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with your web view's delegate method :

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
}
```